# Apache Spark only in Windows standalone mode: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, windows, apache-spark

I'm trying to run my Spark Job on a Standalone cluster on windows, but the execution always fail with a `ClassNotFoundException`:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: yyyyyyy.xxxxxxx.SomeClass$1
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer
.scala:65)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1613)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1774)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:68)

        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:203)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobA
ndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1204)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:11
93)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:11
92)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1192)[actor] handle
```

I tried the exact same Job on a standalone linux cluster and it runs just fine, however it would always fail on windows.

I start my windows cluster with the following commands:

```
 spark-class.cmd org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master
 spark-class.cmd org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://XXXX:7077
```

And I submit my job with:

```
C:\Dev\Spark\spark-1.3.1-bin-hadoop2.6>bin\spark-submit.cmd \
--class Main \
--master spark://XXXX:7077 \
C:\XXXXX\fat-jar.jar
```

And it would fail, it seems my Jar is not present in the worker's classpath.

However on linux with the same launch command the job will succeed. I start my cluster with the provided sh scripts in this case.

Comment: Can you post the logs from the executor?

Comment: @Holden Thanks for your help, it appeared it was either a corrected download or a bug in spark 1.3.1. I updated my application to spark 1.4.0 and the bug disappeared ;)